# C# WPF key held

Tags: c#, wpf, key

I have a problem with key held. Everything works when it's just key down but what about key holding? The code looks like this:

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Left || e.Key == Key.Right || e.Key == Key.Up || e.Key == Key.Down)
    {
       moveBall(3);
    }
}
```

Thanks for replies.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The WPF KeyEventArgs class [has an IsRepeat property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyeventargs.isrepeat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which will be true if the key is being held down.

Example from the article:

```
// e is an instance of KeyEventArgs.
// btnIsRepeat is a Button.
if (e.IsRepeat)
{
    btnIsRepeat.Background = Brushes.AliceBlue;
}
```

Comment: Great job. It's looking nice and working. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

I can see two ways to do this.

The first is to continually check the Keyboard.IsKeyDown for your keys.

```
while (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Left) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Right) || ...)
{
    moveBall(3);
}
```

The second is to simply kick off your **moveBall** method on the KeyDown event and continue doing it until you handle a corresponding KeyUp event.

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Left || e.Key == Key.Right ...)
        // think about running this on main thread
        StartMove();
}

private void Window_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Left || e.Key == Key.Right ...)
        // think about running this on main thread
        StopMove();
}
```