# How to know that one of the buttons on keyboard is pressed and hold (for example Shift)?

Tags: c#, wpf

Now in my program I have a button and user can click it(and process will start), I would like to add such functional - if user click and hold `Shift` button and left click on mouse on the button it will start another process...

So, eventually I need to know - how to trace(know) that user clicked and hold `Shift` button?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# WPF key held](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20818575/c-sharp-wpf-key-held)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check a static class called Keyboard and check for [Modifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.keyboard.modifiers?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Input_Keyboard_Modifiers) like so:

To test for only the shift and no other key held down:

```
if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Shift)
{
   // some logic
}
```

To test if shift is held down while ignoring other modifier keys:

```
if (Keyboard.Modifiers.HasFlag(ModifierKeys.Shift))
{
   // some logic
}
```

This static class resides in `System.Windows.Input` namespace.

Comment: I edited your condition, `ModifierKeys` enum can be used like a flag and a bitwise operation should be done.

Comment: In this case he will get the modifier key for Ctrl + Shift which might not be his intention. My implementation strictly looks for ONLY Shift modifier.

Comment: Indeed, some more explanations can be added about it

Comment: Actually I see that also `Shift + any other key` pass this condition... But in your comment you told that before modifying you posted answer that pass exactly only `Shift event` I am interested to see your answer before it was modified... Could you please additionally add it to your answer?

Comment: I will revert back the original answer.

Comment: Maybe you know what is the possible problem that I get such error the type or namespace name keyboard does not exist in namespace System.Windows.Input (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

You can use KeyDown and KeyUp to check if the key is pressed or released and build further on that:

```
if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightShift))
{
//Insert logic here, an event is probably the way to go.
}
 if (Keyboard.IsKeyUp(Key.LeftShift) || Keyboard.IsKeyUp(Key.RightShift))
{
//Insert logic here, an event is probably the way to go.
}
```

Comment: Do you mean to provide some flag(true\false) implementation in order to trace it?